# Error in updated react bootstrap Accordion component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

This is the updated react bootstrap Accordion component. I used 
`'import {Panel,PanelGroup} from 'react-bootstrap'`
Here it is not taking **Heading**, **title** and **Body**.

This is the error i am getting, any kind suggestions if possible.

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method this is the new
>   updated  react bootstrap component

The code is given below

```
<PanelGroup accordion id="accordion-controlled-example" activeKey=
  {this.state.activeKey} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
  <Panel eventKey="1"> 
    <Panel.Heading>
      <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 1</Panel.Title> 
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Body collapsible>
      Panel content 1
    </Panel.Body> 
  </Panel>
  <Panel eventKey="2">
    <Panel.Heading>
      <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 2</Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Body collapsible>
      Panel content 2
    </Panel.Body>
  </Panel>
</PanelGroup>
```

Comment: are you sure is not 'import Panel,PanelGroup from 'react-bootstrap' ?? without the brackets

Comment: I only saw the brackets for import libraries in `typescript`, never on `Ecma6`

Comment: No, the brackets are correct

Comment: this is new version, old accordion has been changed and updated.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me - https://codepen.io/danegit/pen/mXbNWg